# If I change this javascript function expressions code into java, How can it be represent?

Tags: javascript, java

```
function ClosureFunc(x){
     return function(y){
           retrun  x + "and" + y;
     };
}
```

I'm not used to coding javascript's expression and unique characteristics. And I have experience Java Object-Oriented concept. 
So this function seems a little bit awkward to me. How can it be transformed when I use java code?

Comment: can a java function return a function?

Comment: Function<String, String> closureFunc(final String x) {
    return y -> x + "and" + y;
  }

Comment: @JaromandaX Java does not have function, there are methods. In Java, we can return behaviour, and pass methods as parameter to other methods, so yes java supports closures from v1, they are called anonymous classes. In Java 8, we have a syntactical sugar called lambda in place of anonymous class with a single behaviour.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat - semantics